# How I can assign multiple workflows in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have the following problem: I need to assign many tasks to a single user at the moment, it is possible in SharePoint 2010?

Comment: Can you be more specific? There shouldn't be anything stopping you from creating multiple tasks and assigning them to the same user OR starting multiple (different) workflows on the same item assigning them to the same user.

Comment: I reassign workflows from one person to another, SharePoint 2010 lets me do it one by one, I need to do this by selecting multiple tasks at that moment and change it then. Not if you understand now.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here. You can either use Edit in Datasheet mode to mass edit multiple workflow tasks and change the assigned to field.
Or, you can use a custom solution via the Client Object Model that will use the selected task items to perform a ribbon action that will change the assigned to field.